# An application of the Pressing Down Lemma (Part 1)

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Remember the **Pressing Down Lemma**:

Let $k$ be a regular uncountable cardinal, $S\subseteq k$ be a stationary set and let $f:S\to k$ be such that $f(\gamma)<\gamma$ for every $\gamma \in S$ (such a function is called a regressive function). Then there exists an $\alpha<k$ such that $f^{-1}(\{\alpha \})$ is stationary.

In the article Barely Baire spaces of Fleissner and Kunen the following lemma appears:

**Lemma 4** Let $\chi>\omega$ be a regular cardinal. If $K\subseteq {\chi}^{\omega}$ is closed, and $W=\{f^{*}: f\in K  \}$ is stationary, then there is $C$ club in $\chi$ such that $C\cap C_{\omega}\chi  \subseteq W  $

Where, $C_{\omega} \chi$ is the subset of $\chi$ of ordinals of cofinality $\omega$. Also, if $cf (\chi)> \omega$, we can define a map $*:{\chi}^{\omega}\to \chi$, where $*(f)=f^{*}$ is the least $\alpha$ greater than $f(n)$ for all $n\in\omega$.

For the proof, the authors consider $\sigma\in \bigcup_{n\in\omega}\chi^{n}$ and $W_{\sigma}=\{f^{*} : \sigma\subseteq f\in K\}$. Then consider $\Sigma=\{\sigma :  W_{\sigma} \hspace{0.1cm}\mbox{is stationary}\hspace{0.1cm}\}$. By hypothesis $\Sigma\not=\emptyset$, because $\emptyset\in \Sigma$.

Then the authors affirm the following,

**Claim 4.1** Using the Pressing Down Lemma one can build a function $\theta: \Sigma \times \chi \to \Sigma$ such that

- $\sigma\subseteq \theta(\sigma, \alpha)$
- $\theta(\sigma, \alpha)\not\in \bigcup_{n\in\omega}\alpha^{n}$

**Question 1.** Does anyone have any idea to build this function?, at first I was trying as follows, let $\sigma\in\Sigma$, then $W_{\sigma}$ is stattionary. I don't have an initial idea to be able to define a regressive function $g_{\sigma}:W_{\sigma}\to \chi$.

@Shervin Sorouri, managed to demonstrate this part, you can see the answer in the first comments.

Continuing with the article of Fleissner and Kunen, they consider $C=\{ \gamma < \chi: \theta[ (\Sigma\cap \gamma^{<\omega}    ) \times  \gamma ]\subseteq \gamma^{<\omega} \}$ and they said that $C$ is a club.
Indeed,

- **$C$ is closed.**

Let $\gamma\in C^{\prime}$, we will show that $\theta[ (\Sigma\cap \gamma^{<\omega}    ) \times  \gamma ]\subseteq \gamma^{<\omega}$. Let $(\sigma, \alpha)\in (\Sigma\cap \gamma^{<\omega}    ) \times  \gamma$, so there is $n_{0}\in\omega$ such that $\sigma\in \gamma^{n_{0}}$, consider $m=\max\{\sigma(n_{0}-1), \alpha \}<\gamma$ then there exists $\beta \in ]m, \gamma+1[ \cap (C \setminus \{\gamma\})$, so $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$ and $\sigma\in \beta^{<\omega}$, then
    $\theta(\sigma, \alpha) \in  \theta[ (\Sigma\cap \beta^{<\omega}    ) \times  \beta ]\subseteq \beta^{<\omega} \subseteq \gamma^{<\omega}$. Therefore $C^{\prime} \subseteq C$, that is, $C$ is closed.

- **$C$ is unbounded.**

For this, define 
$$
\begin{array}{lcccl}
f & : & \chi & \longrightarrow & \chi\\
 & & \gamma & \longrightarrow &  f(\gamma)=\sup\{\theta^{*}(\sigma, \alpha) :\sigma \in \Sigma\cap\gamma^{<\omega}, \alpha<\gamma \},
\end{array}
$$
where $\theta^{*}(\sigma, \alpha)=\sup(ran (\theta(\sigma, \alpha)))$, note that $f$ is well defined, that is, $f(\gamma)=\sup\{\theta^{*}(\sigma, \alpha) :\sigma \in \Sigma\cap\gamma^{<\omega}, \alpha<\gamma \}<\chi$, because $\chi$ is an uncountable regular cardinal.

Previously remember the following fact:

> *Proposition 1*. Let $\kappa$ be an uncountable regular cardinal and $f:\kappa\to\kappa$ be a function. Then $\{\alpha<\kappa : 
> > f[\alpha]\subseteq \alpha\}$ is a club in $\kappa$.

Then, by Proposition 1, $\{\gamma<\chi:f[\gamma]\subseteq \gamma\}$ is a club in $\chi$, then $$\tilde{C}=  \{\gamma<\chi: \gamma\hspace{0.1cm} \mbox{is a limit ordinal}\hspace{0.1cm} \mbox{and}\hspace{0.1cm} f[\gamma]\subseteq \gamma\}$$ is a club in $\chi$. Note that $\tilde{C}\subseteq C$. Indeed, let $\gamma\in\tilde{C}$ and let $(\sigma, \alpha)\in (\Sigma\cap \gamma^{<\omega})\times \gamma$, as $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal, there is $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$ such that $\sigma\in \beta^{<\omega}$ then $\theta^{*}(\sigma, \alpha)\leq f(\beta)<\gamma$, so $\theta(\sigma, \alpha)\in \gamma^{<\omega}$.

Finally it is commented that $$C\cap C_{\omega}\chi \subseteq W$$
where $C_{\omega}\chi=\{\beta<\chi : cf(\beta)=\omega\}$.

I tried to demonstrate this last part in the following way.

Let $\gamma\in C\cap C_{\omega}\chi$, as $cf(\gamma)=\omega$, there exists a strictly increasing function $g:\omega\to\gamma$ whose range is cofinal in $\gamma$, that's, $\sup\{g(n) :n\in\omega\}=\gamma$.

Also, as $\theta[ (\Sigma\cap \gamma^{<\omega}    ) \times  \gamma ]\subseteq \gamma^{<\omega}$, choose $\sigma\in \Sigma\cap \gamma^{<\omega}$ and consider $g(0)\in \gamma$ then $$\theta(\sigma, g(0)) \in \gamma^{<\omega}$$

In particular,

1. $\sigma\subseteq \theta(\sigma, g(0))$
2. $\theta(\sigma, g(0))\not\in g(0)^{<\omega}$

Also, as $W_{\sigma}$ is stationary then $\emptyset\not=[g(1), \chi[\cap W_{\sigma}$ so there exists $f\in  K $ such that $g(1)\leq f^{*}$ and $\sigma\subseteq f$

**Question 2.** Does anyone have any idea to build this function? My problem is basically how to make that $f$ when it is built belong to $K$ and so far I also don't know how to use that $cf(\gamma)=\omega$.

Thanks

Comment: I think since this question has been answered before, you might have better luck by posting a separate question and giving links to this one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $\sigma$ and $\alpha$ let $P = W_\sigma - \alpha$ which is still stationary. Now for each $f^* \in P$, let $g_\sigma(f^*)$ be $f(n)$ where $n$ is least such that $f(n) \ge \alpha$. Now using pressing down lemma and the pigeonhole principle, you can find some fixed $n$ and some fixed $\gamma \ge \alpha$ such that $\{ f^* \in P: f(n) = \gamma\}$ is stationary. Now if $n\le |\sigma|$, you are done. Else to fill the gap between $|\sigma|$ and $n$ you can use repeated applications of the pressing down lemma, to get the desired $\theta$.

---

EDIT: [This edit will try to complete the below answer you provided.][Disclaimer: I am using **your** notation.]

As in your answer, let $S = \{f^* \in P: f(m) = \gamma\}$ and suppose $m \gt |\sigma|$. By the fact that $P \subseteq W_\sigma$, we have $f||\sigma| = \sigma$, for any $f^* \in S$. First we inductively choose a finite sequence of stationary sets $\langle S_0, \dots, S_{m-|\sigma|-1}\rangle$ and a finite sequence of ordinals $\langle \beta_0, \dots, \beta_{m-|\sigma|-1}\rangle$, such that $S_0 \subseteq S$, $S_{i+1} \subseteq S_i$, for $i \lt m-|\sigma|-1$. Also we make sure that for each $f^* \in S_i$, $f(i+|\sigma|) = \beta_i$.

This can be done easily, using the pressing down lemma. For the base case $i = 0$, consider $g(f^*) = f(|\sigma|)$ and by the pressing down lemma you have some stationary $S_0 \subseteq S$ and some ordinal $\beta_0$ such that $g"S_0 = \{\beta_0\}$. At the $i$th step just look at $g(f^*) = f(i+|\sigma|)$, and construct $S_i$ and $\beta_i$ as above.

So we wish to build a $\theta \in \chi^{m+1}$ that satisfies the conditions in the question. First let $\theta||\sigma| = \sigma$ and $\theta(m) = \gamma$. Now for $|\sigma| \le i \lt m$, let $\theta(i) = \beta_{i-|\sigma|}$. Now you can see that $W_\theta$ is stationary as it contains $S_{m-|\sigma|-1}$. And also because of $\gamma$ you have $\theta \not \in \cup_{n\in\omega} \alpha^n$.

Comment: How to ensure $g_\sigma$ is regressive? I worry about the possibility that $f$ is an eventually constant function.

Comment: @Hanul, I guess the definition ensures that, no? Because it says $f^*$ is the least ordinal *greater* than all $f(n)$, $n \in \omega$.

Comment: Ah, right, I confuse the definition of $f^*$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Shervin Sorouri for the help, it was very good proof. I got to understand everything. Do you know more applications of the Pressing down lemma?, I am new in this part.

Comment: @user987, No problem! I am glad that I was helpful. I don't have any more applications right off the bat, but I can tell you by my own experience that the pressing down lemma is very important and is widely used. For example when working with trees, you encounter lots of stationary sets and in those areas you use it left and right. As I am still learning set theory myself, I can't say much more, simply because I don't know. But I am sure you can find many experts here or on MO, which can give you more examples.

Answer (score 1):

This demonstration was done by @Shervin Sorouri, in this part I am dividing your demonstration with some previous lemmas.

**Lemma 1** Let $\kappa$ be a regular uncountable cardinal and let $\alpha \in \kappa$. If $S$ is stationary in $\kappa$, then $S\setminus \alpha$ is stationary in $\kappa$.

**Lemma 2** Suppose that $\kappa$ is a regular uncountable cardinal and that $\gamma\in \kappa$. Let $\langle S_{\alpha} : \alpha\in\gamma   \rangle$ be a $\gamma$-sequence of subsets of $\kappa$. Suppose that the set $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\gamma}S_{\alpha}$ is stationary in $\kappa$. Then $S_{\alpha}$ is stationary, for some $\alpha\in\gamma$.

**Proof of Claim 4.1** Indeed, let $\sigma \in \bigcup_{n\in\omega}\chi^{n}$ and $\alpha<\chi$, consider $P=W_{\sigma}\setminus \alpha$, by Lemma 1, $P$ is stationary in $\chi$. Define 
$$
\begin{array}{lcccl}
g_{\sigma} & : & P & \longrightarrow & \chi\\
 & & f^{*} & \longrightarrow &  g_{\sigma}(f^{*})=f(n),
\end{array}
$$
where $n=\min\{n\in\omega : f(n)\geq\alpha \}$. Note that $g_{\sigma}(f^{*})<f^{*}$, for all $f^{*}\in P$, so by Pressing Down Lemma, there is $\gamma<\chi$ such that $g_{\sigma}^{-1}(\{\gamma \})=\{f^{*}\in P : g_{\sigma}(f^{*})=f(n)=\gamma\}$ is stationary, note that $\gamma\geq\alpha$. Finally, define
$$
\begin{array}{lcccl}
h & : & g_{\sigma}^{-1}(\{\gamma \}) & \longrightarrow & \omega\\
 & & f^{*} & \longrightarrow &  h(f^{*})=n,
\end{array}
$$
where $n\in\omega$ is such that $g_{\sigma}(f^{*})=f(n)$. Note that $g_{\sigma}^{-1}(\{\gamma \})=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}h^{-1}(\{n\})$, then by Lemma 2, there is $m\in\omega$ such that $h^{-1}(\{m\})=\{f^{*}\in g_{\sigma}^{-1}(\{\gamma \}):h(f^{*})=m\}=\{f^{*}\in P : f(m)=\gamma\}$ is stationary.

- If $m\leq |\sigma|$, then $\theta(\sigma, \alpha)=\sigma$, in this case $\theta(\sigma, \alpha)\not\in \bigcup_{n\in\omega}\alpha^{n}$, because $\sigma(m)=f(m)=\gamma\geq\alpha$.
- If $m>|\sigma|$,

**Claim 4.1.1** There are a finite sequence of stationary sets $\langle S_{0} , \cdots, S_{m-|\sigma|-1}\rangle$ and a finite sequence of ordinals $\langle \beta_{0} , \cdots, \beta_{m-|\sigma|-1}\rangle$ such that $S_{0}\subseteq S$ and, for $i<m-|\sigma|-1$, then $S_{i+1}\subseteq S_{i}$ and if $f^{*}\in S_{i}$ then $f(i+|\sigma|)=\beta_{i}$.

**Proof of Claim 4.1.1** In fact, for $i=0$, consider $$
\begin{array}{lcccl}
g_{0} & : & S & \longrightarrow & \chi\\
 & & f^{*} & \longrightarrow &  g_{0}(f^{*})=f(|\sigma|)<f^{*},
\end{array}
$$
By the Pressing down lemma, there exists $\beta_{0}<\chi$ such that $g^{-1}_{0}(\{\beta_{0}\})=S_{0}$.

For $0<i<m-|\sigma|-1$, consider $$
\begin{array}{lcccl}
g_{i} & : & S_{i-1} & \longrightarrow & \chi\\
 & & f^{*} & \longrightarrow &  g_{i}(f^{*})=f(|\sigma|+i)<f^{*},
\end{array}
$$
By the Pressing down lemma, there exists $\beta_{i}<\chi$ such that $g^{-1}_{i}(\{\beta_{i}\})=S_{i}\subseteq S_{i-1}$.

Note that, if $f^{*}\in S_{i}$ then $f(i+|\sigma|)=\beta_{i}$.

Now we will build $\theta\in \chi^{m+1}$, let $\theta|_{|\sigma|}=\sigma$ and $\theta(m)=\gamma$. Then, if $|\sigma|\leq i<m$, define $\theta(i)=\beta_{i-|\sigma|}$.

Finally, note that $S_{m-|\sigma|-1}\subseteq W_{\theta}$. In fact, let $f^{*}\in S_{m-|\sigma|-1}$, in particular, $\sigma\subseteq f\in K$ and $f(m)=\gamma$. By Claim 4.1.1, $f(i+|\sigma|)=\beta_{i}$ for $i<m-|\sigma|-1$, so $f\in W_{\theta}$.

Comment: Firstly, I want to apologize for not being to post a complete answer, because I'm in the middle of a trip right now and I don't have access to my laptop and I have to use my mobile phone.

Comment: And secondly, for the last part, you have already found $\theta | |\sigma|$ and $\theta(m)$. So to find $\theta(i)$ for $|\sigma| \le i \lt m$, you can use the pressing down lemme repeatedly for functions $g_i$ where $g_i(f^*) = f(i)$. I hope this makes it more clear. If not, in a few days I'll return home, and I will try to write a more complete answer. Also I'm glad to help!

Comment: Also note that since the number of such $i$ is finite, you can choose these stationary sets in a finite number of steps using induction.

Comment: I finally returned home and have posted a more complete answer, addressing the final part of the argument. I hope it is helpful.